# Why does my LD_LIBRARY_PATH get an uninstalled terminal launch?

Tags: 16.04, oracle

In general, what I do to get the result:

I drive a team:
    `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib`

Checking:
    `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Result:
          `/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib`

When I restart or open the new terminal my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is disabled.

How to fix it?

Comment: See [Persistent environment variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Persistent_environment_variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new terminal creates a new shell and it does not have access to your variable.

If you want the variable available at each login for your user, put the command in `~/.bashrc`

If it should be available to all users, edit `/etc/bash.bashrc` instead.

Comment: An edit and an upvote here though!  **;-)**